# How do I attach BatchWriteItem Permission to my IAM role policy via the serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless

Hey I just started with Serverless so I am trying to be as precise as possible with my problem.

I am using AWS AppSyncDynamoDB resolvers to use GraphQL to store and retrieve data in my Amazon DynamoDB table. Everything was working fine until I wanted to use Batch operations specifically BatchDeleteItem.

I got the error that my user was missing the necessary permissions even though I specified in my Serverless.yml file the following:

```
Effect: “Allow”

Action:

- dynamodb:DescribeTable
- dynamodb:Query
- dynamodb:Scan
- dynamodb:GetItem
- dynamodb:PutItem
- dynamodb:UpdateItem
- dynamodb:DeleteItem
- dynamodb:BatchWriteItem
- dynamodb:BatchDeleteItem
```

I went into the IAM Management console and saw that within the created policy BatchWriteItem and BatchDelteItem were missing:

```
{
“Version”: “2012-10-17”,
“Statement”: [
{
  “Action”: [
    “dynamodb:DeleteItem”,
    “dynamodb:GetItem”,
    “dynamodb:PutItem”,
    “dynamodb:Query”,
    “dynamodb:Scan”,
    “dynamodb:UpdateItem”
  ],
  “Resource”: [
    “arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:MYID:table/MYTABLENAME”,
    “arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:MYID:table/MYTABLENAME/*”
  ],
  “Effect”: “Allow”
}
]
}
```

When I add the necessary permission manually to the policy everything is working. But it is really important for me that this policy is created over the serverless.yml file and sls deploy.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks Ben!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually solved my issue was that the lambda function of Appsync was called over the Serverless Appsync plugin and within this role the BatchWriteItem was missing.
I changed the within the package.json file the plugin version to the GitHub version in which this problem is already fixed, but until today not released. This fixed it:
    `"serverless-appsync-plugin": "https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin.git#e33b5cfd"`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question fully (at least not the part that's asking "why isn't BatchRead/Write getting attached"), but it is a valid option in your scenario where you require the exact permissions covered by an AWS managed policy. With that in mind, you can use [DynamoDB crud policy.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverlessrepo/latest/devguide/using-aws-sam.html#dynamo-db-crud-policy)
Your policy will look like this (when attached to the Policies tag of your resource):

```
Policies:
- DynamoDBCrudPolicy: 
  TableName: !Ref YourTableName
```

Since the only policy DynamoDBCrudPolicy is missing is DescribeTable, you can try add that one separately if you need it.